# Cannot install the easytags vim plugin

Tags: vim

I would really like to use easytags, but after following Odding's installation instructions, that is first installing misc and *then* installing easytags, at startup vim is throwing the "misc is not installed,easytags is broken" error.  I am just unzipping them into my vim directory as I have always done with other plugins.. Any suggestions?  thanks!

Comment: You should ask this question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation is indeed a simple unzipping of both `misc.zip` and `easytags.zip` **into the same `~/.vim/` directory**.

Check out the `:scriptnames` command from Vim to see whether all files got successfully sourced. After a manual `:runtime autoload/xolox/misc.vim`, it should contain entries like:

```
205: ~/.vim/autoload/xolox/misc.vim
278: ~/.vim/plugin/easytags.vim
```

If you're still facing problems, please open an issue on the [plugin's issue tracker](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags/issues).